# View Windows Backup file selection set without wizard

Tags: windows-7, backup

The Windows 7 Backup tool wizard is painfully slow. Is there a way to view the file selection set another way?

Windows backup always acts as if you're running it for the first time and steps through selecting a destination and so on. I just want to inspect the existing selection set and not chance inadvertently changing it. Is the selection set in a registry key or a file somewhere?